# CGContextSetLineDash is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cgcontext

```
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, [2, 2], 2)
```

With the above line of code I get the error:

> CGContextSetLineDash is unavailable: Use setLineDash(self:phase:lengths:)

I've tried `CGContext.setLineDash` to no avail, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setLineDash` is not a static/class method, it's an instance method:

```
context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [2, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, a CGContext is a pseudo-object with instance methods.

Thus, for example:

```
class V : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        c.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [2,2])
        // ... 
    }
}
```